Equality in Clifford's theorem for special divisors
$\DeclareMathOperator{\deg}{deg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
$
I'm working through Rick Miranda's book "Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces" and problem VII.1.F is about the cases where equality holds in Clifford's theorem (Theorem VII.1.13).
Suppose $X$ is an algebraic curve of genus $g$ and $D$ is a special divisor on $X$ for which equality holds in Clifford's theorem. Then the claim is that either $D$ is canonical or principal or $X$ is hyperelliptic and $D$ is linearly equivalent to $\pi^* (E)$, where $\pi\colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ is the double covering and $E$ is a positive divisor of degree at most $g-1$. To prove this, Miranda gives a hint to use induction on the degree of $D$. My idea for the proof was the following:
It is not hard to show that cases $\deg(D) = 0$ and $\deg(D) = 2g-2$ correspond to $D$ being principal and canonical, respectively. Also $\deg(D)=2$ case is quite immediate. Suppose now that $\deg (D) = 2k$, where $k\geq 2$ and suppose by induction that the claim is true for divisors with degree $2k-2$.
Since equality holds in Clifford's theorem, we have $\dim L(D) = k+1$ and by Riemann-Roch $\dim L(K-D) = g-k \geq 1$. If $g-k=1$ then $\deg(D) = 2g-2$ and this implies $D$ is canonical. Thus we may assume $g-k>1$. Suppose now that $D$ is very ample, i.e. for all $p,q\in X$, we've $\dim (D-p-q) = \dim L(D)-2 $. Then we have a embedding $\phi_D \colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^k$ so that the image $Y=\phi_D (X)$ is a smooth projective curve with $\deg(Y) = \deg(D) = 2k$. Now by Castelnuovo's bound (Theorem VII.3.19) we can see that $$
g \leq (k-1)\frac{2(2-1)}{2} + 2 = k+1,
$$ which contradicts the assumption $g>k+1$. Thus $D$ cannot be very ample. Also if $\dim L (D-p-q) = \dim L(D)$ then we get a contradiction with Clifford's theorem applied to $D-p-q$. Thus there must be points $p,q\in X$ s.t. $\dim L(D-p-q) = \dim L(D)-1$ and one can check that $D'=D-p-q$ satisfies equality in Clifford's theorem and hence the result follows by induction.
My problem is that this proof uses the Castelnuovo bound, which to me seems like an overkill since the result appears later in the book than the problem. So I was wondering if anyone has an idea how to prove the claim using induction on the degree as I did but only using results that appear before the problem in Miranda's book.
